# Trigger the pattern attribute of input box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to execute the check for a pattern of an input box using javascript. The reason I need to do this, is because the form gets submitted via ajax every time something is changed in an input box. So this has to be delayed, the check has to be performed, and if incorrect, the ajax process must be stopped. This is all fine, except, how can I trigger the pattern attribute? obviously without using submit.

HTML

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" />
```

**EDIT**

I want to be lazy and not re implement the pattern. E.g. I want to get this for free

[image]

[See in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r39Ru/8/)

This nice message is contained in the title attribute of the input box and obviously shows so nicely when the user tries to submit something that does not match the pattern.

well someone asked for some reason I don't understand for the ajax snippet. btw `handleUTF8Decode.php` is solving a charset problem and then including the actual page. 
There you go:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/mycompany/handleUTF8Decode.php",
            data: jform.serialize(),
            dataType: 'html',
            async: true,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#ajax-status").html("Processing");
            },
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $("#ajax-status").html("ERROR " + "<div class='ajaxResponse'>"+data+"</div>" );
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is the `onchange` code that triggers the AJAX?

Comment: That's not the code @tymeJV was asking for...

Comment: I recommend less hostility if you want us to do your homework or job for you. [This SO Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291152/javascript-fallback-for-the-html5-pattern-attribute-on-input) will push you in the right direction.

Comment: @RenéRoth thanks for the link, it is not what I am looking for though. I don't want to reimplement the pattern. I want to trigger its functionality, including the title display on error, if possible.

Comment: i still don't understand btw why you would ask for the `on('change')` code. It is totally basic

Comment: @Toskan - because, as basic as it is, people blow it all the time and pasting the code may reveal that. People sometimes catch their own mistake when they are pasting the code.  And if people don't see how your `$.ajax()` is *actually* being triggered they have to start guessing.

Comment: I hope you are also validating the format of the date and that it's an actual valid date on the server too, when your ajax call posts it. Never (ever) trust the "validated" data coming from a web form.

Comment: @StephenP ok fair point. It seems to me though, that the ajax request is, as request suggests, a separate request/submit. So listening to submit events on the form of our dom _seems_ wrong. See `jform.serialize()` . It could be, that the ajax request has their own submit.

Comment: I agree with your comment, and my second comment is just to say that I use client-side validation to save round trips to the server, but I still don't trust what comes across the wire. The answer from @Bergi seems the right direction, but I haven't tried it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

In response to the OP's comment below...

I threw this together pretty quick at the end of a long work day, so I apologize for the haggard-ness. A full working example (with extensive notes) can be found on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/wuyum/1/edit?js,output). This example shows how you can use jQuery UI's `datepicker` and `tooltip` widgets in combination with the input field's standard `oninput` event to create a dynamic field that does client-side form validation without the need to submit the form data.

I realize that this may not be the most elegant way of doing this, but it is an option that I haven't seen suggested in this forum. *Then again, there's probably a good reason for that...*

Nevertheless, here's a quick look at the framework -- to see it in 'action', you can check out its [JS Bin page](http://jsbin.com/wuyum/1/edit?js,output). *Please excuse the formatting, I'm too lazy for CSS at the moment.*

```
// I've gone ahead and removed most of the code and notes for
// brevity. See: [http://jsbin.com/wuyum/1/edit?js,output]
$(function () {
    // Internal function used to incrementally validate the user's
    // input (valid for both mm/dd/yyyy & dd/mm/yyyy formats).
    function validateInput(contents) {
        var rgx = /^(\d{1,2}(?:\/(?:\d{1,2}(?:\/(?:\d{1,4})?)?)?)?)$/;
        return rgx.test(contents);
    };

    // Internal function used to check a valid date format against
    // a valid date (e.g. 99/99/2014 is not a valid date).
    function checkDate(date) {
        return !isNaN(new Date(date).getDate());
    };

    // Create a new datepicker object and use its onSelect event to
    // run through your AJAX call...
    $('#date').datepicker({
        // onSelect will be called when the user either selects a date
        // from the widget, or uses the Return/Enter key on submission.
        onSelect: function (date) {
            // By now the date has already been validated, client-side,
            // in two-part. First the RegEx matched a mm/dd/yyyy format
            // and then we confirmed that the date wasn't erroneous with
            // checkDate(). If the user submitted an invalid date (say
            // '44/44') the widget will automatically reset the date to
            // 'today'. Alternatively, you could call checkDate() again
            // during this event -- that's really your call.

            // Execute your AJAX call
            // $.ajax() ...
        }
    }).tooltip({
        // Define a non-delegated tooltip to use as a prompt...
    }).on('input', function () {
        // Handle the forms RegExp and format validation here...
    });
});
```

It's worth noting that `datepicker`'s default format is `mm/dd/yyyy`. This can easily be changed, but you should be warned that if your goal is to offer the user the option of entering either `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`, you will run into some issues unless to first validate with format was being used. For example:

```
10/06/2014 --> October 6th 2014 (mm/dd/yyyy)
10/06/2014 --> June 10th 2014 (dd/mm/yyyy)
```

Hope this can be of some help to you.

---

**Original Answer**

From your RegEx pattern, it looks like your trying to validate the field based on a standard date format `mm/dd/yyyy`.

If this is the case, and you want to validate the format on every change to the field, I would suggest using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) and the [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) widget -- leveraging the `datepicker`s `onSelect` event. Like so:

```
// where #date is the id of <input id="date" type="text"/>
$('#date').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(date) {
        // $.ajax() here
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could manage the RegEx validation and AJAX call within the `input` field's `onchange` event.

```
// obviously you'd want to be more specific than simply grabbing the first
// input element found.
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onchange = function (e) { ... };
```

Lastly, you could look into HTML5 and its implementation of the [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes) `type` attribute.

Comment: does the onSelect get triggered even if manually entering the date?

Comment: @bartlb - are you sure it's not in standard date format `dd/mm/yyyy`? More of the world uses that format than m/d/y

Comment: @StephenP Totally valid point. To my defense, there was only so much I could assume from the RegEx though.

Comment: @Toskan - The `onSelect` event is fired when the user hits the  Return/Enter key. I will add a more detailed example to my answer to clarify.

Comment: I'll accept this answer even though it does not solve the original question. Btw I like the checkDate function, didnt know they exist. And I forgot about jqueries tooltip implementation as well

Comment: btw what do all the `?)` do? I dont understand, in your regexp

Comment: The trailing `?` quantifiers are used to allow the regex string to operate dynamically on the users input. In this case, the date string is handled as a whole pattern, with sub-patterns, each used to evaluate and allow entries such as `01/`, `01/12`, `01/12/1`, etc. The `?` quantifier at the end of each sub-pattern validates the whole pattern whether 0 or 1 of the directly preceding sub-patterns exist. As a simplified example: Evaluate a field for two words, separated by a space. `rgx = /^(\w+)\s?(\w+)?$/`. Used to check `oninput`, this will allow `John`, `John `, `John Doe` as the user types.

Answer (score 10):

`pattern` is nothing to be "triggerd". You just check the [validity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) of the element in question:

```
jform.find("input[pattern]").prop("validity").patternMismatch // boolean
```

Comment: that is cool, didn't know this. I will specify something additional in my question to get everything across

Comment: This is from far the best answer. Thank you Bergi

Answer (score 1):

Showing an errormessage while the user is still changing the value isn't the best pattern. Simply use an input type="date" and bind to the 'input' event. The input event on this type is only triggered, if there is no type mismatch.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/8e95N/

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="date"]').on('input', function(){
        //your ajax
        console.log($.prop(this, 'value'));
    });
});
```

Comment: good example, want to get value of HTML5 pattern attribute, get using same idea.