# Html <input pattern> handling with JavaScript - fails on exceed

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I'm having trouble with handling HTML `<input>` `pattern` attribute. I would like to change the color of indicator basing on pattern fulfifllment. It doesn't go green until the input is 3 characters long but it fails to turn red again when it exceeds 20 chars. Here's the HTML code:

```
<p>
    <canvas id="Circle6" width="30" height="30"></canvas>
    Imię
    <input type="text" pattern=".{3,20}" required title="3-20 characters required" id="FirstName" oninput="checkInput(id, name)" name="Circle6">
</p>
```

and the Javascript function:

```
    function checkInput(id, name) {
        var input = document.getElementById(id);
        isValid = input.value.search(new RegExp(input.getAttribute('pattern'))) >= 0;
        var c = document.getElementById(name);
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        if (isValid)
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        else ctx.fillStyle = "red";

        ctx.fill();
    }
```

the line `isValid = input.value.search(new RegExp(input.getAttribute('pattern'))) >= 0;` was taken from [Javascript fallback for the HTML5 "pattern" attribute on <input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291152/javascript-fallback-for-the-html5-pattern-attribute-on-input)

EDIT: The circle is drawn on page load by:

```
function drawCicle(elementid) {
    var c = document.getElementById(elementid);
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(15, 15, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, Chrome. happens on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `.test` instead of `.search`, because the latter will return a match as long as you have an input that exceeds 3 characters (in other words, if your input string exceeds 20 characters, you will still get an array returned (which will be evaluated as true)).

Also, you have to anchor the regex pattern to the front `^` and the end `$` of the string, so you simply prepend the former and append the latter to the pattern attribute value: `new RegExp('^'+input.getAttribute('pattern')+'$')`.

```
function checkInput(id, name) {
    var input = document.getElementById(id),
        re = new RegExp('^'+input.getAttribute('pattern')+'$'),
        c = document.getElementById(name),
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    if (re.test(input.value))
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
    else ctx.fillStyle = "red";

    ctx.fill();
}
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/pmdye1y0/3/

Comment: nope, I have it somewhere else. As I said, it turns green but fails to turn red again.

Comment: You should've included that important info beforehand — **and that is why we ask OPs to construct examples themselves** as they are the ones who fully understands the contexts of the question.

Comment: You're right and I'm sorry for that but as you can see on your fiddle, it's not working properly. It remains green even if you put more than 20 chars.