# HTML5 Pattern fallback for Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Safari does not support HTML5 pattern... The input pattern below works fine but is in need of a workable fall back.

```
<input type="password" required pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$" name="password" id="password">
```

fallback attempt... (from another answer dated 2011)

```
var input = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];


input.addEventListener('change', function() {
        console.log('Is valid?',  input.value.search(new RegExp(input.getAttribute('pattern'))) !== -1);
}, false);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript fallback for the HTML5 "pattern" attribute on <input>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291152/javascript-fallback-for-the-html5-pattern-attribute-on-input)

Comment: @pstenstrm that's the example i tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the event you're listening to. The event `change` is essentially the same as `blur` in this case.

Change the event you listen to `keyup` or `input`:

```
input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    console.log('Is valid?',  input.value.search(new RegExp(input.getAttribute('pattern'))) !== -1);
}, false);
```